# .bat renaming the file with the content inside the parentheses

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, previously I was here because I wanted to rename my file based on something that I created, I ended up doing it and it was a simple thing, but now, I am with another thing that I think it's better, so I have this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
chcp 65001
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\leandro.batista\Desktop\SAMPLES RENAMER"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\leandro.batista\Desktop\SAMPLES RENAMER\BACKUP"
FOR /f "delims=()" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pdf" ') DO (


    REN "%%a" "%sourcedir%\*.pdf"
    PAUSE

    )
```

I tried to rename the file with what was inside the parentheses of the file name, for exemple :

Input:

```
File Name: blablabla(exampleIwantToExtract)
```

OutPut:

```
File Name: (exampleIwantToExtract)
```

When I run the bat it says that has a syntax error and I am not pretty sure why, I have an ideia tho, it might be the `REN` code, or better, it must be the `REN` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `delims`, you should also use the right `token` (`2` for your example filename(s). If you don't define it, it defaults to `1`, which would give you `blablabla`)

But for renaming a file, you need also the full name. Best method is to use two nested `for`loops. The outer loop a plain `for` to get the (old) filename and an inner `for /f` loop to tokenize the filename to get the new name:

```
for %%a in ("%sourcedir%\*.pdf") do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
    ECHO move "%%~fa" "%destdir%\(%%b)%%~xa"
  )
)
```

`%%~fa` gives you the full qualified file name (including drive and path)
`%%~na` gives you the name of the file only
`%%~xa` gives you the extension of the file (of course you could simply type `.pdf` instead,
but `%%~xa` gives you additional flexibility)

Note: `ren` doesn't support destination path. Therefore I used `move` instead.

Comment: It worked like a gem dude, didn't knew the power of the delims and I am kinda of lost in the %% parts, it's kinda of strange, anyways, thanks !

Comment: read `for /?`. Then read it again. Then sleep over it and read it again. That's how I learned it `:)`

Comment: Okay man, without the Echo it's giving me an error, do you know why ? @Stephan

Comment: always hitting the same trap... `ren` doesn't support destination path. Use `move` instead. (I'll edit my answer)